# Triggering an alert based on response from API

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm making a basic react form app and I'm trying to target a specific field within an API.

`{ "summary": { "outcome": "Approved", } },`

However, the issue is I cannot figure out how to target this specific field within the body of the fetch. The idea is to create an alert window based on what the outcome field spits out. I think I need to declare the outcome field as a variable somehow, and then call that variable into an alert, using if/else statements. Below is the full body of my code:

```
class Form extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);

        // declare input fields in state
        this.state = {
            name_first: '',
            name_last: '',
            address_line_1: '',
            address_line_2: '',
            address_city: '',
            address_state: '', // state code format. e.g. "NY"
            address_postal_code: '',
            address_country_code: '', // country code format, e.g. "US"
            document_ssn: '',
            email_address: '',
            birth_date: '' // must be in ISO 8601 format YYYY-MM-DD
        };
    
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }
    
    // handle change events
    handleChange = event => {
        const thisAttribute = event.target.value;
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: thisAttribute
        });
        console.log(this.state.name_first)
    }
    
    // handle submit events + API call
    handleSubmit = (events) => {
        
        const token = ""
        const secret = ""
    
        let data = `${token}:${secret}`;
        let encodedString = btoa(data)
        let proxyLink = '-insert proxy url-'
        let URL = '-insert endpoint url-'
        let proxyURL = proxyLink + URL
    
        const payload = this.state
    
        const options = {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(this.state),
            headers: {
              accept: 'application/json',
              authorization: `Basic ${encodedString}`
            }
          };
          
            fetch(proxyURL, options)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(response => console.log(response))
            .catch(err => console.error(err))
             events.preventDefault();
        }

}
```

Any ideas would be welcome here.

Expecting to call the outcome field into an alert window and display a message based on the response. Something like the below:

`

```
//     .then(response => {
//         if(response.data === "Manual Review") {
//             alert("Thanks for submitting your application, we'll be in touch shortly")
//         } else if (response.data === "Denied") {
//             alert("Sorry, your application was not successful")
//         } else {
//             alert("Congratulations, you have been approved!")
//         }
//     }) 
//     events.preventDefault();
// }
```

`

Comment: `response.data.summary.outcome` should do the trick. Or something similar. Basically JSON data (which is what you're dealing with) is parsed automatically by JavaScript and you can access it using the dot notation like I've shown above.

Comment: hey @noodlejs So I tried calling that but I'm getting an error `App.js:68 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'summary')`

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, JSON-type data is automatically parsed and accessible using the dot notation. I see your comment about `Cannot Access Property of Undefined`, so here's the full code to try.

This should do this trick:

```js
fetch(proxyURL, options)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
        const { summary } = data;
        const { outcome } = summary; 

        if (outcome === "Manual Review") {
            alert("Thanks for submitting your application, we'll be in touch shortly");
        } else if (outcome === "Denied") {
            alert("Sorry, your application was not successful");
        } else {
            alert("Congratulations, you have been approved!");
        }
    });
```

This code will make the fetch request and, if it's successful, parse the content as JSON. Then it will pipe that result into the following `then()` method and that's where you should be processing the JSON data.

There are a few ways to parse JSON.

```js
const data = {
   summary: {
      outcome: "Approved"
   }
};

// This will access the data directly. 
// If anything is undefined, it will throw an error
data.summary.outcome

// This will pull summary out of response.data and
// if it is undefined, the variable summary will also be undefined
const { summary } = data;
const { outcome } = summary;

// This will access the summary property of the response.data
data['summary']
```

All of these JSON parsing techniques are valid.

Comment: hey @noodlejs I tried this but am still getting an error: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'summary' of 'response.data' as it is undefined.
    at App.js:62:1`

Comment: Silly me, I had a bug in my answer. It's updated now. In the second `then` you should just treat it like the data. So it should be like this `.then(resp => resp.summary.outcome)`. Give that a try.

Comment: that worked! perfecto. Thank you so much for the help on this, this was driving me crazy.

Comment: @samohtebag513 awesome!! No problem at all, I'm glad to hear it worked. Don't forget to accept this answer if there are no more problems with it :)